# How to allow zooming in between range only in chartjs-plugin-zoom

Tags: plugins, zooming, chart.js

plugin-zoom ( https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom )

I want to show zooming in between provided range only like { min-zoom : 0,max-show:100} over the axis. Any idea about same?

Answer (score -1):

You can add zoom range only,this range will be your canvas width.

```
zoom: {
        // Boolean to enable zooming
        enabled: true,

        // Enable drag-to-zoom behavior
        drag: true,

        // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable 
        // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
        mode: 'xy',
        rangeMin: {
            // Format of min zoom range depends on scale type
            x: null,
            y: null
        },
        rangeMax: {
            // Format of max zoom range depends on scale type
            x: null,
            y: null
        }
    }
```